# A question about windows api DestroyWindow

Tags: windows, win32gui

I want to konw if there is a message pump in DestroyWindow,and if the message WM_DESTROY will be processed before DestroyWindow return.

[This is my test code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh6fm.png)

And the message posted before DestroyWindow still remains in the message queue when the WM_DESTROY is processed:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcoP3.png)

but when DestroyWindow return,the message posted before DestroyWindow will be removed:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yuvch.png)

Comment: Calling PostMessage just before the dialog closes and the program terminates is not a good idea.

Comment: Normally we do *not* like code in images but for this question I don't need to look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no message *pump* in `DestroyWindow`. I submit that it is pretty obvious that any messages destined to a window that's being destroyed are dropped from the queue when the window is destroyed. Even in Windows 3.1, the alternative would be unthinkable because you can't know if another program's window is about to be destroyed. How much more so now when we have pre-emptive threading now.